# How can I retrieve selection count of each item under ListView in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created an android app that contains a ListView with some items in it. I want to get the details of each item with the count of it being selected.

Ex : 1st item is selected twice, 2nd item is selected 5times etc.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I am misunderstanding your question but, its simple just update the list view on every selection using `notifyDatasetChanged()` method of your list view adapter

Comment: Not sure I got your point. I want track all the items and their selection count. Assume that I want to highlight those items which are selected more than remaining ones.

Comment: How are you recording the selection of the items ... is it the count of the clicks of the item that is stored . or is it some thing else kind of selection

Comment: Presently I do not have any count of selection. I am developing android for the first time. So I have used long click event to show menu on selection of any item. I want to track the count and then store it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a data structure in Adapter. HashMap is a good idea, where key is position and and value is count. In adapter use getter, to get HashMap in actvity (via adapter.getMap();) .

call map.put(position,count) in onclick of view.

HashMap ensures only one key (position) is maintained with latest count (since HashMap maintains unique keys and overrides previous one if the key already exists)

Let me know if you require the code as well.

Comment: Thanks Kay. Let me try this approach. If required will request you to provide code.